# java.io.FileNotFoundException on posting data from Android

Tags: android, http, ssl, https

I am trying to post data from my android device to server through HTTPS Url, I am getting this error

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException:https://URL
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might be giving the wrong input stream, are you using file input stream or what? Seems like it regards your url as a file path.

Comment: BufferedReader resultReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));